# KendoUI Treeview with AngularJS uncheck checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm using KendoUI (v2015.1.318) with AngularJS (v1.3.14). After every click on a node, the data will be fetched from an API. 
After selecting some items and clicking on the button "add", the items will be added in a seperated list, the expanded treenodes must stay visible but all the 
checked items must be unchecked.

After I iterated through the datasource to uncheck the checked items , I have call SetDataSource again. When I have expanded a lot of nodes and checked a few, the UI freezes some seconds while it's processing.

I was wondering if there wasn't a more efficient way to execute this.

I made an example without API call:

```
    $scope.saveTreeFields = function () {
    var data = $scope.tree.dataSource._data;
    for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        checkChildren(data[i]);
    }
    function checkChildren(data) {
        if (data.checked) {
            data.checked = false;
        }
        if (data.items !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0, j = data.items.length; i < j; i++) {
                checkChildren(data.items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
     $scope.tree.setDataSource(data)
};
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RcbyS3t9mLEyyspRo0DF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer from Telerik itself.

> you can call the dataItem set("checked", false) method to notify the
>   model of the field change, and the TreeView will update automatically.

Code changes

```
    $scope.saveTreeFields = function () {
    var data = $scope.tree.dataSource.data();
    for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        checkChildren(data[i]);
    }
    function checkChildren(data) {
        if (data.checked) {
            data.set("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.items !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0, j = data.items.length; i < j; i++) {
                checkChildren(data.items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```